# Filter multiple images predictions based on a given threshold

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having some trouble trying to filter tensors based on a given threshold.

I have a batch containing two images:

> [2, 300, 300, 3]

I make predictions on this batch and receive the following values:

> boxes[2, 300, 4]
>
> scores[2, 300]

I would like to filter the scores on a based threshold value let's say 0.10, how would I be able to filter the scores and then filter the corresponding boxes?

So the output would look like:

> output[2, 50, 4] (when there are 50 boxes left after filtering)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the TF solution, the following should work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mask = tf.math.greater(scores,0.1)
boxes_above_thresh = tf.boolean_mask(boxes, mask)
scores_above_thresh = tf.boolean_mask(scores, mask)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  res = sess.run([scores_above_thresh, boxes_above_thresh])
```

Having said this, this will return a `(number of boxes, 4)` type array. That is, it won't return you a `(2, 50, 4)` array, rather a `(100, 4)` array.

**Edit**: Getting a Tensor with `(2, x, 4)` type output

I think you are looking for tf.ragged_tensor. Which is suited for your purpose. The following solution will result in a `tf.RaggedTensorValue`.

```
mask = tf.math.greater(scores,0.1)
boxes_above_thresh = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(boxes, mask)
scores_above_thresh = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(scores, mask)

with tf.Session() as sess:

  res1, res2 = sess.run([scores_above_thresh, boxes_above_thresh])
```

Comment: Yea that's kinda the problem, since using this solution I wont be able to check which boxes belong to which image...

Comment: Is there a guarantee that there will be equal boxes for each image?

Comment: I found a way to get the indexes separatly, but having trouble with the merging, since the shapes are different: `indexes = tf.map_fn(
            lambda index:
            tf.where(tf.keras.backend.greater(scores[index, :], threshold)), tf.range(batch_size),
            dtype=tf.int64)
        tf.print(tf.shape(indexes))`

Comment: @Thomas edited my answer. I think the solution in the edit will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
filtered_indices=np.where(scores>thresh)
filtered_scores=x[filtered_indices]
filtered_boxes=boxes[filtered_indices]
```